# Convert Hibernate List without initialize it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities: Deck and Card

```
@Entity
class Deck {
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Card> cards;
}

@Entity
class Card {
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Deck> decks;
}
```

And I have a Model for each entity

```
class DeckModel {
    private String name;
    private List<CardModel> cards;
}

class CardModel {
    private String name;
    private List<DeckModel> decks;
}
```

Now I want to convert a `Deck` in a `DeckModel` so I created this two functions:

```
DeckModel convert(Deck deck) {
    DeckModel model = new DeckModel();
    model.setName(deck.getName());
    model.setCards(deck.getCards().stream()
            .map(card -> convert(card))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return model;
}

CardModel convert(Card card) {
    CardModel model = new CardModel();
    model.setName(card.getName());
    model.setDecks(deck.getDecks().stream()
            .map(deck -> convert(deck))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return model;
}
```

The problem with this piece of code is that when i convert `Card(s)` in `CardModel(s)` I trigger the lazy load of all cards related to the deck I'm converting but what I want is to decide later on in my application if I want or not to fetch all the `Card(s)` related to the `Deck`.

Is there an easy/standar way to do this?

Comment: if you don't want the collection when copying the data to the Model object, then simply don't call `deck.getDecks()`. just let the Model objects have empty lists, no?

Comment: The problem is that I can potentially need the collection later in my application, but because I'm not sure if I need I don't want to fetch it now

Comment: Is it a problem that you fetch the collection at copy time? is it that huge? usually you don't need to think about it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate in for loop and set it manually as the models in list differ.
You cannot use **Reflection** as the models field differ.
else you could use BeanUtils.copyProperties() to map fields of DeckEntity into Deck 
and set that Deck object in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify in advance if a lazy hibernate collection is initialized through the method:

Hibernate.isInitialized

example:

```
CardModel convert(Card card) {
    CardModel model = new CardModel();
    if (Hibernate.isInitialized(deck.getDecks())) {
         model.setName(card.getName());
         model.setDecks(deck.getDecks().stream()
            .map(deck -> convert(deck))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    return model;
}
```

By using it you can verify its state and if not initialized just return empty list.

Comment: With this solution if deks has not been initialized before I can not initialize them later on in my application.

Comment: @b1zzu do I have the feeling you are looking for Open Session in view pattern (anti pattern)? Of course you can not initialize it whenever you want. That is the idea of the session. You have open session you can initialize, you don't have a session you can not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I implemented for my own problem, maybe it can be useful to someone else.

I have created a `LazyList` object which require a `ListInitializer`, on the first operation the `LazyList` will call `ListInitializer` which will return a `List`, the `LazyList` will then delegate all operations to the `List` returned from the `ListInitializer`. In my specific case the `ListInitializer` will convert and return the converted `List`. So doing my `List` will not be converted if the `LazyList` will never be used.

```
public class LazyList<T> implements List<T> {

    private final ListInitializerSingleton<T> singleton;

    public LazyList(ListInitializer<T> initializer) {
        this.singleton = new ListInitializerSingleton<>(initializer);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return singleton.list().size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return singleton.list().isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return singleton.list().contains(o);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return singleton.list().iterator();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return singleton.list().toArray();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public <T1> T1[] toArray(@NotNull T1[] a) {
        return singleton.list().toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        return singleton.list().add(t);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return singleton.list().remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(@NotNull Collection<?> c) {
        return singleton.list().containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(@NotNull Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return singleton.list().addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, @NotNull Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return singleton.list().addAll(index, c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(@NotNull Collection<?> c) {
        return singleton.list().removeAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(@NotNull Collection<?> c) {
        return singleton.list().retainAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        singleton.list().clear();
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return singleton.list().get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int index, T element) {
        return singleton.list().set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        singleton.list().add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(int index) {
        return singleton.list().remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return singleton.list().indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return singleton.list().lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        return singleton.list().listIterator();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        return singleton.list().listIterator(index);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return singleton.list().subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ListInitializer<T> {
        List<T> initialize();
    }

    private class ListInitializerSingleton<T> {

        private final ListInitializer<T> initializer;

        private List<T> list;

        ListInitializerSingleton(ListInitializer<T> initializer) {
            this.initializer = initializer;
        }

        List<T> list() {
            if (list == null) {
                list = initializer.initialize();
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DeckModel convert(Deck deck) {
    DeckModel model = new DeckModel();
    model.setName(deck.getName());
    LazyList<CardModel> cards = new LazyList<>(() -> {
        deck.getCards().stream()
                .map(card -> convert(card))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    })
    model.setCards(cards);
    return model;
}

CardModel convert(Card card) {
    CardModel model = new CardModel();
    model.setName(card.getName());
    LazyList<DeckModel> decks = new LazyList<>(() -> {
        card.getDecks().stream()
                .map(deck -> convert(deck))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    })
    model.setDecks(deks);
    return model;
}
```